# Airflow Operator BigQueryTablePartitionExistenceSensor Question

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to use this BigQueryTablePartitionExistenceSensor operator in Airflow and I was wondering if this operator checks whether the partition is fully loaded or can potentially mark to success even if the data isn't complete yet.

For example, if my table is partitioned on DAY and the load for 20220420 has started but isn't complete, would this sensor trigger? Or, would it wait until that load step has been completed before marking the sensor to success?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Operator will not wait until your data has loaded, it will just check for the existence of the partition value at that moment in time. So if a single row gets inserted into that partition then this sensor would return True. [See the sensor code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/355b008043fe78b7807e184b6887ec5d16e044e8/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L278) that gets called by this operator.

An idea I've used in the past for similar problems has been to use a sentinel **Label** on the partitioned table to mark a load as "in-progress" or "done"

Answer (score 0):

As has already been answered, it does not await anything except the existence of the partition.

If your data is streamed into partitions, and you have ordered delivery, you can probably add a sensor for the next-day partition — on the assumption that the previous day is complete when events have started streaming into the next.

If the load is managed by the same Airflow instance, I'd suggest using an ExternalTaskSensor on the load job. If not, you might be able to use the more generic SqlSensor, and run a custom SQL query on metadata tables to determine if a partition is complete, perhaps you can add a label or something with the Load job that you then query for.